# How do you generate URL rewrites in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

Is there a way to force Magento 2 to redo all of the product/category urls? The majority of the site is fine with urls such as category-name/product.html but a few categories refuse to conform to the same rules.

Before I could get rid of the table and reindex but this option no longer exists.

Answer (score 7):

I currently use this to update the url keys of certain products:

1. Update 'url_key' attribute through Magento Import
2. Admin --> Products Catalog --> Select the products you imported the new url_key for --> Actions: Update Attributes --> Websites: Add to website
   You can just tick the website it is already assigned to. This way the product gets 'updated' and it writes the new imported url_key to the url_writes table

Comment: This method still works on 2.1.2.

Comment: This solution work for me. can you please explain why ? I mean i try to save to save product and save category but it's not working but when i update attribute it works how ?

Comment: I'm getting "The value of attribute "EXAMPLE_CODE" must be set" error when trying to update website.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Regenerate a Url rewrites](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites) extension (it allow to generate/regenerate a Url rewrites of products and categories) .

To re-generate all Url rewrites of the categories/products in all stores (it support a multistores) run:

```
$> bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
```

To regenerate Url rewrites in the specific store view (e.g.: store view id is "2"):

```
$> bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate 2
```

Comment: Just double checked, it doesn't work unfortunately. :-/

Comment: Some products has direct links, some ones - not. The last leads to 404.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Magento 2 isn't regenerating rewrites on reindexing. Url rewrites are generated when product/category/page is saved/imported. So probaly your only solution is to write a script which will go through all products and resave them.

You can read more about this "issue" on [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2619).

Answer (score 0):

If (like me) you accidentally deleted some of the Magento 2 URL rewrites for a product and so you see horrible URLs like the following:

```
catalog/product/view/id/1/category/2
```

You can simply edit the category for the products where you are missing URL rewrites and save it.

Magento 2 then re-creates URL Rewrites for the products in that category.

e.g.

```
/mycategory/myproduct.html
```

This works in Magento 2.1.6

Comment: For some reason this does not work in my case.

Comment: @Webninja same here. I do not know why saving the category doesn't generate the URL keys again. Oleg Koval solution works fine tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the magento cli you can type this cmd

For a target store :
$ php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --store-id=1

For a all stores :
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate

Comment: You forgot to mention that this needs the extension from oleg koval...